# How to determine the complement when the predicate is not a simple inclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm given sets defined using set-builder notation and I'm not entirely sure how to take the complement of the set. I ask a general question in Part I, then a related question in a more complicated case that is relevant to the proof I'm trying to construct in Part II.

**Part I**

I know for set defined in set-builder notation where the predicate is simply an inclusion of the set elements in another set, like
\begin{equation}
X = \{ x \in U : x \in B \cup C \}
\end{equation}
then the complement is
\begin{align}
X^c &= \{ x \in U : x \in B \cup C \}^c \\
    &= \{ x \in U : x \notin B \cup C \} & \text{(this is the definition I've seen)} \\
    &= \{ x \in U : \neg(x \in B \cup C) \}.
\end{align}

But can I use the negation of the predicate in general to derive the set-builder form of the complement?

For example, let
\begin{equation} A = \{ x \in U : f(x) \in B \hspace{2pt} \wedge \hspace{2pt} g(x) \in C \},
\end{equation}

then would the complement simply be

\begin{align}
A^c &= \{ x \in U : \neg(f(x) \in B \hspace{2pt} \wedge \hspace{2pt} g(x) \in C) \} \\
&= \{ x \in U : f(x) \in B^c \hspace{2pt} \vee \hspace{2pt} g(x) \in C^c \}?
\end{align}

**Part II**

In a more complicated case, if I'm given the following definitions for the inverse of the mapping $f : U \rightarrow V$

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(X) = \{ f^{-1}(F_v) : F_v \in X \}, \hspace{10pt} X \subseteq 2^{V}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(F_v) = \{ x \in U : f(x) \in F_v \}, \hspace{10pt} F_v \in 2^V.
\end{equation}

Then given some specific $A \in f^{-1}(X)$ where $X \subseteq 2^V$, what would the set builder form of $A^c$ look like?

I was thinking that I could say, from the definition of $f^{-1}(X)$, that $A$ could be expressed in set-builder notation as follows.

Because $A \in f^{-1}(X)$ there must be some $F_v \in X$ such that

\begin{align}
A &= f^{-1}(F_v) \\
  &= \{ x \in U : f(x) \in F_v \}.
\end{align}

Using the same $F_v$, if my assumption about how to take the complement of a set in set-builder notation is correct, then I could then write $A^c$ as

\begin{align}
A^c &= (f^{-1}(F_v))^c \\
    &= \{ x \in U : f(x) \in F_v \}^c \\
    &= \{ x \in U : \neg(f(x) \in F_v) \} \\
    &= \{ x \in U : f(x) \in F_v^c \} \\
    &= f^{-1}(F_v^c).
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you are correct. If I define some subset $A$ of a fixed "universal" set $U$ by
$$A:=\{x\in U:\phi(x)\}$$
where $\phi$ is some set theory formula, then
$$A^{\mathsf{c}}:=U\setminus A=\{x\in U:\neg\phi(x)\}.$$

For the second part, it seems your question boils down to whether the complement of pre-image equals the pre-image of the complement, which it does!

**Proposition**
Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be sets.
Let $ f:X\to Y $.
For each $ B\in\mathscr{P}\left(Y\right) $, $ f^{-1}\left(Y\setminus B\right)=X\setminus f^{-1}\left(B\right) $.

*Proof.*
Let $ B\in\mathscr{P}\left(Y\right)$ be arbitrary.
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}\left(Y\setminus B\right)&=\left\{z\in X:f\left(z\right)\in\left(Y\setminus B\right)\right\}\\
&=\left\{z\in X:f\left(z\right)\in \left\{y\in Y:y\notin B\right\}\right\}\\
&=\left\{z\in X:f\left(z\right)\notin B\right\}\\
&=\left\{z\in X:z\notin f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right\}\\
&=X\setminus f^{-1}\left(B\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Very interesting thank you Alberto. Just a quick question In your proof going from line 3 to line 4. This is based on the observation that if $f(z) \notin B$ then, from the definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ we know that $z \notin f^{-1}(B)$ right?

Comment: That's right. Line (3) is a subset of Line (4) because of what you mentioned. But also mentally justify Line (4) is a subset of Line (3) in order to justify the equality.